Is there a "universal" sense in which [0,2] is larger than [0,1] beyond Lebesgue measure?
This is a very basic question and may be better suited for a philosophy site but I would like to know if there is any rigorous way to answer it before I try somewhere else.
I know the sets $[0,1]$ and $[0,2]$ have the same cardinality so in that sense they're the same size. The best way that I know of to express one being larger than the other (and in particular, twice the size of the other one) is by using the Lebesgue measure.
But this is just one measure with a few nice properties out of infinitely many possible measures. I feel like saying that $[0,2]$ is larger than $[0,1]$ simply because there is some nice measure for which this holds fails to capture the real sense in which one is larger than the other one.
For instance one could say that, out of all functions between both sets there is at least one function (the identity function) from $[0,1]$ to $[0,2]$ but not the other way around. So no matter how many functions there are between them, there is at least one that only goes one way, which I guess could be some sense in which one is "universally" larger than the other one.
So I wonder if there is anything more fundamental than the Lebesgue measure that could capture this notion that one set is larger than the other one?

In most senses they are the same size. There is not only a bijection between them but a very nice one (multiplication by $2$), which is for example continuous with continuous inverse. So they’re homeomorphic as topological spaces.

It's not clear what you're after exactly, but you could of course just say that one is bigger as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $[0, 1] \subsetneq [0, 2]$. You can also say that one has a larger diameter than the other, i.e. $2 - 0 > 1 - 0$.

Intuitively, maybe $[0,2]$ is bigger than $[0,1]$ but if the first represented centimetres and the second inches then the second is bigger.

@NaïmFavier Thanks, I overlooked the subset thing, and it feels pretty close to the kind of answer I was looking for. Regarding your second point, is this a topology thing? I know 2 - 0 > 1 - 0 arithmetically but I think you mean something else since I don't know why you call them diameters.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter#Diameter_of_a_set
